# SOLD label only shows in product grid, need also to show on product page

Tags: magento-1.9

I got this code placed in catalog/product/list.phtml, but that only makes the label SOLD for a product to show on category pages. I would like it to appear on every page where the product is shown. Should a place the code somwhere else? see live on https://www.mediaboxshop.nl/media-spelers

Thanks.

```
<span class="sticker-wrapper top-left">
<span class="<?php if ($_product->getStockItem()->getIsInStock() == 0) { echo 'sold-out'; } ?>"> 
  <?php 
       if ($_product->getStockItem()->getIsInStock()) {
         echo "&nbsp;";
        }else{ 
           echo "Sold"; 
         } 
    ?> 
 </span>
```

I placed it after this code in list.phtml

```
 <ul class="products-grid category-products-grid itemgrid itemgrid-adaptive itemgrid-<?php echo $columnCount; ?>col<?php if($gridClasses) echo $gridClasses; ?>">
        <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
            <li class="item">

                    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true); ?>" class="product-image">

      <div class="product-image-wrapper" style="max-width:<?php echo $imgWidth; ?>px;">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file you want to modify for the product view is:

```
/catalog/product/view.phtml
```

Adding your code in here should add your sold for product pages however the product may show in other blocks like related products etc.

For related and upsell below files should be modified:

```
/catalog/product/list/related.phtml
```

And

```
/catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml
```

Change your $_product variable to $_item on these template files however.